# initializing values to constructor

Tags: java, variables, constructor, instance

In the following code I have declared 2 user defined constructors, one without parameters and the other one with 3 parameters, in both the constructors I am assigning values to the instance variables and when the main method is executed the output for constructor without parameters is 2 and the o/p for constructor with 3 parameters is 0 in the first way, but when I try the second way the o/p for zero parameters constructor is 2 and for the 3 parameters constructor is 15, where I am passing the arguments while object creation, now I don't understand why in the first way the output is zero.

```
public class Main {

    int x, y, z;

    Main() {
        x = 2;
        y = 2;
        z = 2;
    }

    // first way
    Main(int x, int y , int z) {
        x = 20;
        y = 20;
        z = 10;
    }

    // second way
    Main(int x, int y , int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int sub() {
        int m;
        m = x + y - z;
        System.out.println("the value is " + m);
        return m;
    }
}
```

Following is the main method:

```
package demo;

public class Maintest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Main s = new Main();
        int s1 = s.sub();
        Main s3 = new Main(10,10,5);
        int s2 = s3.sub();
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I saw your code. When you use the constructor in //first way

you get the answer as 0 because the  values 20, 20, 10 that you are initialising to variable x,y,z respectively gets initialised to constructor variable x,y,z not to the class variable x,y,z.

When you use constructor //second way

values get initialized to the class variables x,y,z because of the use of "this" keyword. this refers to the class variable hence when you use in second way constructors shows the result as 15.

Comment: well now I understand the scope of that variables x=20 is within that constructor my method cannot acces that variables so that is the reason I a getting o/p as zero

Answer (score 5):

When you use `x=20` you are assigning a new value to the parameter `x` passed to the constructor, not assigning that value to instance member. When you write `this.x`, it clearly binds to the instance member.

If you still confusing about them, change the parameter names to some other and check.

Comment: Main(int a, int b , int c){
  a = 20;
  b = 20;
  c = 10;
  this.x=a;
  this.y=b;
  this.z=c;
 }

Comment: I did this change but I am not able to get it what is happening can you please elaborate, as I am assigning value to the parameter of the constructor then the o/p should be 15 instead it is 0

Comment: When you just did `Main(int a, int b , int c){ a = 20; b = 20; c = 10;`, is there any involvment in x there ? No right ? Hence the values are zero

Comment: Main(int a, int b , int c){ a = 20; b = 20; c = 10; this.x=a; this.y=b; this.z=c; } as per this change the o/p is fine its showing 30 @SureshAtta

Comment: @VinayPBhosale Well in the last you are assigning values. `this.x=a; this.y=b; this.z=c;`

Comment: well now I understand the scope of that variables x=20 is within that constructor my method cannot acces that variables so that is the reason I a getting o/p as zero

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to current object reference on which the method is called. So using `this` before the variable refers to current object instance variable.

If you dont use `this` then they are pointing to the variable passed in the argument.

However if you changed function parameter name and then use only `x` it will refer to current object instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

If instance variable name is similar to argument name, at that time use 'this' explicitly to solve the ambiguity issue for JVM.

```
Main(int x, int y, int z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

This is the standard practice.

But if you change argument name then its not mandatory to use 'this'.

```
Main(int xx, int yy, int zz) {
    x = 20;
    y = 20;
    z = 10;
}
```

Here it refers to instance variables and will give you proper results.

Cheers!!!

Comment: well now I understand the scope of that variables x=20 is within that constructor my method cannot acces that variables so that is the reason I a getting o/p as zero